# Tableless model JSON serialization in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have tableless model (like it was shown in #219 railscast):

```
class MyModel
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :attr1, :attr2, :attr3, :attr4

  private
    def initialize(attr1 = nil)
      self.attr1 = attr1
    end

    def persisted?
      false
    end
end
```

Then I'm trying to render JSON in controller:

```
@my_model = MyModel.new
render json: @my_model.to_json(only: [:attr1, :attr2])
```

but it renders JSON with all the attributes of the model.

I've tried to add

```
include ActiveModel::Serialization
```

but it didn't change rendered JSON.

How can I render JSON with only necessary attributes of my tableless model?

I'm using Rails 3.2.3

**Update**

Thanks, guys. It seems you're all almost right. I combined your solutions and got this:

Model:

```
include ActiveModel::Serialization

...

def to_hash
  {
    attr1: self.attr1,
    attr2: self.attr2,
    ...
  }
end
```

Controller:

```
render json: @my_model.to_hash.to_json(only: [:attr1, :attr2])
```

I really don't know whose answer to be accepted.

**Update 2**

Suddenly new strangeness appeared. One of the attributes is array of hashes. It was like this:

```
attr1: [[{name: "name", image: "image"}, {name: "name", image: "image"}],
        [{name: "name", image: "image"}, {name: "name", image: "image"}]]
```

But now it lost all its content and looks like this:

```
attr1: [[{}, {}], [{}, {}]]
```

Maybe anyone know how to fix it?

**Update 3** :)

Erez Rabih's answer helped. Using `slice` instead of `to_json` solved the problem. So, final solution is:

```
render json: @my_model.to_hash.slice(:attr1, :attr2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it isn't straight forward but how about:

```
render :json => @my_model.attributes.slice(:attr1, :attr2)
```

You will also be required to define an attributes method as:

```
def attributes
   {:attr1 => self.attr1.....}
end
```

Thanks for the comment bender.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because Object::as_json is calling internally (look at this: http://apidock.com/rails/Object/as_json), and it has no options like :only or :except, so you can overide method to_hash in your class, e.g.:

```
def to_hash
  {:attr1 => self.attr1, :attr2 => self.attr2}
end
```

and to_json will do exactly what you want.

Certainly, another option is to override method to_json ...

Comment: I'm having the same problem as OP and this didn't seem to change anything for me...

Answer (score 0):

You may mix your initial approach (including AM serialization modules) with Erez' one as the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html) suggests.

```
class MyModel
    include ActiveModel::Serialization::JSON
    ....
    def attributes
       {:attr1 => self.attr1.....}
    end
    ...
end
```