# Rails - Dinamically select attributes to be serialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization

I'm using ActiveModel Serializers to serialize my models and I'm constantly in need to create a new serializer in order to satisfy the needs of an controller without including unnecessary information into another.

```
class ContactGroupSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :contacts, :contacts_count, 
             :company_id, :user_id

  def contacts_count
    object.contacts.count
  end
end
```

Is there a way to define a single serializer, such as the one above, and them dinamically select which attributes to be included on my controller response?

```
class ContactsGroupsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...
    render json: @contact_groups // here I would like to return only id and name, for example
  end
end
```

I know I can achieve that by creating another serializer, but I wouldn't like to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tableless model JSON serialization in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374240/tableless-model-json-serialization-in-rails)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just define a method in your `application_controller.rb` to which you can pass all your objects to be rendered with array of methods to be returned as response..like for example,

```
def response_for(object, methods = [:id])
  if object.blank?
    head :no_content
  elsif object.errors.any?
    render json: { errors: object.errors.messages }, status: 422
  else
    render json: build_hash_for(object, methods), status: 200
  end
end

private #or in your `application_helper.rb`

def build_hash_for(object, methods)
  methods.inject({}) do |hash, method|
    hash.merge!(method => object.send(method))
  end
end
```

In your particular case above, you can just

```
class ContactsGroupsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    ...
    response_for @contact_groups, [:id, :name]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting approach. The problem is that I still want to be able de define 'virtual' attributes that are available only on the serializers, such as the contacts_count attribute. So the idea is to still have a single serializer for each model. The problem is to have lots of serializers for the same model.